# Does the equation in Aphex Twin's "Equation" -song have any real resemblance?

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Does the equation in Aphex Twin's "Equation" -song have any real resemblance?

The song's title is:

$$\Delta M_i^{i-1} = - \alpha \sum_{n=1}^N D_i[n]\bigg[ \sum_{j \in C[i]} F_{ji} [n-1] + F ext_i [n^{-1}] \bigg]$$

Intuitively, given the context, one'd expect it to be some sort of DSP formula. But it 1) doesn't give definitions for the contents of $D, F, C$. It also has some weird $ext$-function (unless it's meant to read $Fext$, perhaps "$F$ external").

It does have some resemblance to some sort of signal processing system, because it's a combination of terms and some of the terms rely on "past" observations (the $n-1$ index).

Comment: They can take any equation they want from whatever source they want, and most of the time it remains nonsense, as it is here. I've seen worse examppes than this...

Comment: I only managed to find a shoddy image of the back cover/title, but it seems transcribed a bit wrong, it looks more like $M_i^{-1}$, $\{$ and $\eta$ and maybe a $\phi$... too bad I don't have the album :-)